# how to format json to output

Tags: json, tcl, eggdrop

I have this json link, https://predb.ovh/api/v1/?q=@name%20IfIca.Icssssy

The returned JSON is

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "message": "",
    "data": {
        "rowCount": 0,
        "rows": [],
        "offset": 0,
        "reqCount": 20,
        "total": 0,
        "time": 0.003080273
    }
}
```

The output status and message working.
When `rowCount` is also in the output, I get an error:

> Tcl error : can't read "rowCount": no such variable

```
bind pub "-|-" !search pub:test
proc pub:test { nick host handle channel arg } {

    set name [lindex $arg 0]
    set tok [http::geturl "https://predb.ovh/api/v1/?q=@name%20$name"]

    set aadata [json::json2dict [http::data $tok]]
    http::cleanup $tok  
    dict with aadata {
        putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :status $status"
        putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :rowCount $rowCount"
    }

}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error. Also, the json contains the key `data`, so you may want to use a different dict name or map this key to a different name. You do have `name` not properly set however, there should be a space between `name` and `[lindex ...`. Maybe that's what causing the issue, because then, the json is different and doesn't have `rowCount`.

Comment: i have the same error when i replace data with aadata; set aadata [json::json2dict [http::data $tok]] , dict with aadata {

Comment: Did you also add the space? I was still editing my comment earlier above, sorry.

Comment: i have seen now, name is fixed, copy failr. how man you with lindex? set rowCount [lindex $aadata 1] so? then is output "rowCount success" and with  set rowCount [lindex $aadata 5] is output empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the key `rowCount` is not directly under the `aadata` dict, it resides in a sub-dict.

If you want to use `dict with` you'll have to do

```
dict with aadata {
    putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :status $status"
    dict with data {
        putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :rowCount $rowCount"
    }
}
```

or, simpler:

```
putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :status [dict get $aadata status]"
putnow "PRIVMSG $channel :rowCount [dict get $aadata data rowCount]"
```